# Use Parallel.ForEach on method returning task - avoid Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I've got a method which takes `IWorkItem`, starts work on it and returns related task. The method has to look like this because of external library used.

```
public Task WorkOn(IWorkItem workItem)
{
    //...start asynchronous operation, return task
}
```

I want to do this work on multiple work items. I don't know how many of them will be there - maybe 1, maybe 10 000.
`WorkOn` method has internal pooling and may involve waiting if too many pararell executions will be reached. (like in `SemaphoreSlim.Wait`):

```
public Task WorkOn(IWorkItem workItem)
{
    _semaphoreSlim.Wait();
}
```

My current solution is:

```
public void Do(params IWorkItem[] workItems)
{
    var tasks = new Task[workItems.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < workItems.Length; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = WorkOn(workItems[i]);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

Question: may I use somehow Parallel.ForEach in this case? To avoid creating 10000 tasks and later wait because of `WorkOn`'s throttling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually is not that easy. You can use `Parallel.ForEach` to throttle the amount of tasks that are spawned. But I am unsure how that will perform/behave in your condition.

As a general rule of thumb I usually try to avoid mixing `Task` and `Parallel`.

Surely you can do something like this:

```
public void Do(params IWorkItem[] workItems)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(workItems, (workItem) => WorkOn(workItem).Wait());
}
```

Under "normal" conditions this should limit your concurrency nicely.

You could also go full `async`-`await` and add some limiting to your concurrency with some tricks. But you have to do the concurrency limiting yourself in that case.

```
const int ConcurrencyLimit = 8;
public async Task Do(params IWorkItem[] workItems)
{
    var cursor = 0;
    var currentlyProcessing = new List<Task>(ConcurrencyLimit);
    while (cursor < workItems.Length)
    {
        while (currentlyProcessing.Count < ConcurrencyLimit && cursor < workItems.Length)
        {
            currentlyProcessing.Add(WorkOn(workItems[cursor]));
            cursor++;
        }

        Task finished = await Task.WhenAny(currentlyProcessing);
        currentlyProcessing.Remove(finished);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(currentlyProcessing);
}
```

As I said... a lot more complicated. But it will limit the concurrency to any value you apply as well. In addition it properly uses the `async`-`await` pattern. If you don't want non-blocking multi threading you can easily wrap this function into another function and do a blocking `.Wait` on the task returned by this function.

In key in this implementation is the `Task.WhenAny` function. This function will return one finished task in the applied list of task (wrapped by another task for the `await`.

Comment: Erm...why can't we just use [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can add this to the first solution if you don't want to use the values proposed by .NET.

Comment: Many thanks @Nitram, I'll go with Parallel.ForEach as you showed. Mixed with ParalelOptions should be more than enough. Thanks also for second option - in more demanding situations that may be the solution.